# Supporting another fragment identifier in AngularJS (besides #)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

We have an AngularJS app in PROD for several years now. We are beginning to see issues in a couple of scenarios where the URL links to our app from other places (like Excel, etc) are causing issues - because it's considered a special char (I won't elaborate for brevity).

So, we are trying to support, along with this:

app.mycomp.net/#/arg1

... also something like this:

app.mycomp.net/HASH/arg1

So, # and "HASH" should both behave the same. We are also fine with detecting "HASH" in the URL and reroute it to #.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: In HTML5 mode, the hash isn't needed. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - HTML5 mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html5-mode).

Comment: Yes, I understand, I have seen forum notes on how to get rid of the #, but as a first step, we want to switch to replacing # with HASH.... hoping that will be an easier step to ensure backward compatibility and push to prod.

Comment: Sounds like a [Car with square wheels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels) question.